# Adding a cart review block to One-Step-Checkout Extension from AddWeb Solutions. Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to know(step-by-step) how to **add a cart** review block(one with quantity updater, product image thumbnail and info), to my **One Step Checkout** from AddWeb Solutions. Im having trouble importing the block through xml in that particular one page checkout page.
Thank you.